# iOS magnify the view not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Hi i am trying to magnify the view with same place finger touch (Y value). I wrote below code but, it gives half of magnified view remains blur.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"%@", context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, - touchPoint.x, - touchPoint.y + (self.scaleAtTouchPoint? 0 : self.bounds.size.height/2));
    [self.viewToMagnify.layer renderInContext:context];
}
```

here frame **width** and **height** is 80. **Scale** is 1.5. if i give scale = 1 gives correct result.

but the result will be like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi any one help me. I struck in this

Comment: you give effects on text or Imageview or View ??

Comment: I applied To UIView and follow this.https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass. But i want magnify on the same place touched.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method setNeedsDisplay to redraw just like this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // some code here 

    //redraw
    [magnify setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```